# SSH from one docker container to another that is using --network flag?

Tags: docker

I am attempting to ssh from a docker container into another, but the container I am trying to ssh into needs the --network host flag to be used, and therefore has no IP address.

I understand that that container is using my hosts port 22 so I changed the ssh port in the container that I am trying to ssh into to port 2200 by adding "Port 2200" to my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file

But the container still has no IP address because of the --network flag. So how do I ssh into a container that has no IP address from another container?

I am starting one container with the command

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged \
--network host \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /run/netns:/run/netns \
--pid="host" \
-w $CLAB_WORKDIR \
-v $CLAB_WORKDIR:$CLAB_WORKDIR \
--name sshtest \
ghcr.io/srl-labs/clab bash
```

The other command is just a Ubuntu container that is just started with `docker run -it --name ubuntu ubuntu`

Comment: Please update your question to show exactly how you are starting the two containers.

Answer (score 0):

Start both containers in the same network

First, create a network with driver type, I prefer bridge:

```
docker network create networkie --driver bridge
```

You can also IP-range and subnets using `--subnet` and `--ip-range`.

Then run both containers in them:

```
docker start --<your flags> container-1 --network networkie`

docker start --<your flags> container-1 --network networkie`
```